# Positioning a Div above website content, using position:relative

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Im trying to position a drop down menu selection box in the top right hand side of my website, however i am having a problem with positioning. I want this drop down box to be on top of the rest of the website rather than just pushing all of its content out of the way.

I have tried to use both position absolute and relative positioning to the dropdown however both have their problems.

Problem with position:absolute; and right:0; is that the drop down goes to the far right of the website however the drop down has to be within the website internal wrapper which is 1140px wide. Please see the screenshot, as you can see the dropdown goes past the red line which represents the edge of the website internal content wrapper. I have tried to solve this by using right:200px or a percentage however it never will work properly because when tested on other monitors and resolutions the dropdown appears in all different places.  Here is the screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PpGy.jpg

I also tried using relative positioning and float:right; this works quite well because the dropdown is contained within the internal wrapper. However the problem is that all of the websites content is pushed down out of the way. Please see the screen shot attached, (as before the red line represents the edge on the website wrapper. Screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IliOS.jpg I have tried using z-index:1000; however this did not do anything.

I would much prefer to go with the position:reliative option if possible, it just seems a lot neater than playing around with pixels and persentages with position:absolute;

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="main_header">
        <div class="main_header_content">
            <div id="main_header_logo">
                <a href="pages/#.php"><span class="helper"></span><img class="logo" src="images/navigation/logo.png" width="250"></img></a>
            </div>
            <div id="main_header_links_wrapper">
                <div id="main_header_links">
                    <ul>
                        <label for="touch"><span class="main_header_link_categories">Categories</span></label><img class="header_link_icon" src="images/navigation/arrow_bottom.png" width="12"></img>
                        <a href="pages/#.php"><li class="header_link_padding">Newest</li><img class="header_link_icon" src="images/navigation/arrow_right.png" height="12"></img></a>
                        <a href="pages/#.php"><li class="header_link_padding">Top 100</li><img class="header_link_icon" src="images/navigation/arrow_right.png" height="12"></img></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" id="touch"> 
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="slide_wrapper">
                    Test
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#main_header_links_wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    height:64px;
}
#main_header_links {
    display:inline-block;
}
#main_header_links ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height:64px;
}

#main_header_links li {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#main_header_links a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#main_header_links a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.header_link_icon {
    padding-left:5px;
}
.header_link_padding {
    padding-left:25px;
}
.main_header_link_categories {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.slide {
  clear:both;
  height:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:1140px;
  margin:0 auto;
}



#touch {position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 0px;}    

#touch:checked + .slide {
    height: 500px;
    width:450px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Use position: relative; and then, position it with left: right: top: bottom:..

Comment: But the website is still pushed out of the way, my problem is that the website moves. I want the drop down to be above the website.

Comment: I've told you how to control the positioning so keep trying until it's the way you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the wrapper the `position: relative;`. Every element with `position: absolute;` inside the wrapper will then be positioned alongside the wrapper and not the browser window anymore.
So you can use `position: absolute;` on the dropdown and have no problem with a relative element, which has an effect to other elements.

E.g.:

```
.main_header_content {
    position: relative;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```